# The ... directory is not writable

Tags: php, kohana

Подскажите, хочу установить движок kohana, а там вроде ошибка, посмотрите пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: Нет прав на запись в Logs и Cache

Comment: абсолютно верно
и совет автору вопроса
читайте внимательнее текст ошибки
там все написано

Comment: А как сделать эти права?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так там же все написано:

> The /var/www/vhosts/mackay.kz/httpdocs/application/cache/ directory is not writable.
> The /var/www/vhosts/mackay.kz/httpdocs/application/logs/ directory is not writable.

Установи на папки application/cache и application/logs права на запись и будет счастье.